# Item losing focus in java

Tags: java, focus, swt

I have a two panels in my application, Panel 1 has tree structure, on clicking of one of the items in tree structure, I can see some information filled in text and combos in another panel 2. Issue reproduces like below:
1. Click on item in tree structure, and click on text field in panel 2, selected item looses focus and I can not see item name in panel 1.
Can somebody help in solving this issue. Attached is the image for more description

[image]

Comment: Only a single component can have focus at any one time, the moment you  click on the text field, the tree will loose focus...Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: item selection losing focus in panel 1 is ok but it should not vanish displaying of name in tree structure

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses